# Why Does the Trace of the following Double Derivative Expression Vanish?

Tags: index-notation

I need some help completing the last part of this problem.

**Problem:**

For the position vector $r$ such that $r = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \sum_{i=1}x_i^2$, show that the trace of the following expression
$$\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}_i}\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}_j}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$$ vanishes.

**Attempt at a Solution:**

The trace can be found by summing up the diagonal elements $(i = j)$
$$ \sum_i \frac{\partial{}^2}{\partial x_i^2}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right) = \sum_i\frac{\partial{}}{\partial x_i}\left(-\frac{x_i}{r^3}\right) = \sum_i\frac{3x_i^2}{r^5}-\frac{1}{r^3}$$

I am not sure how this sum cancels out to zero. Thank you.

Comment: Factor out the $3/r^5$. Note that $\sum x_i^2=r^2$

Comment: The definition of $r$ seems wrong which may be the reason why you cannot terminate your computation?